# Converting polygon to sf in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, mapping, r-sf

Using the tutorial here: https://www.r-spatial.org/r/2018/10/25/ggplot2-sf-2.html (in the section called "States (polygon data)"), I'm trying to convert polygons to an sf object.

```
library("maps")

states <- st_as_sf(map("state", plot = FALSE, fill = TRUE))
head(states)
```

I get the error message: `Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : argument ".f" is missing, with no default`

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it's confusing `map()` from the `purrr` package with `map()` from the `maps` package. Try:

```
states <- st_as_sf(maps::map("state", plot = FALSE, fill = TRUE))
```