# Can't get regional geometries to work with maps of the US (R)

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf, tigris, rmaps

TLDR: Trying to graph some simple US data by census regions and I wanted to put an outline surrounding the regions, but I can't seem to get the regional shapefiles to work.

Hi All,

I'm new to graphing geographic data in R and am trying something simple (US data by census region) but can't quite get some of my design elements to work. I was trying the code from this post ([Mapping by US Census Divisions in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65585964/mapping-by-us-census-divisions-in-ggplot2)) and can't seem to get the shapefile for the outlines of the census regions to work properly. Here's the code from the other post:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tigris)
library(sf)
library(maps)

div_dat <- states(cb = FALSE, resolution = '20m') %>%
  st_drop_geometry() %>%
  select(NAME, DIVISION) %>%
  mutate(ID = tolower(NAME))

# get state data, convert to sf, join with division data
states <- maps::map("state", plot = FALSE, fill = TRUE) %>%
  st_as_sf() %>%
  left_join(div_dat)

# create division polygons
div <- states %>%
  group_by(DIVISION) %>% 
  summarize()

# plot it
ggplot() + 
  theme_void() +
  geom_sf(data = states, 
          aes(fill = as.numeric(DIVISION)), 
          color = 'white') +
  geom_sf(data = div, 
          color = 'black', 
          fill = NA,
          size = 1) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c() +
  coord_sf(crs = 5070) +
  labs(fill = NULL)
```

However, whenever I get to the block to create division polygons I get this error:

Error in wk_handle.wk_wkb(wkb, s2_geography_writer(oriented = oriented,  :
Loop 0 is not valid: Edge 236 crosses edge 239

I imagine this is something simple that I'm doing wrong with the shapefiles, but I'm not sure what the issue is, or how to solve it. I tried turning off spherical geometry and using st_make_valid() but neither of them solved the issue. How should I try to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Two ways around this, and I'm not sure which is better. #1 is to change the crs (I used web mercator '3857'), make it valid, and then change the crs back to the original.  #2 is to set `sf_use_s2(FALSE)`.

Both examples below:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tigris)
library(sf)
library(maps)
library(patchwork)

div_dat <- states(cb = FALSE, resolution = '20m') %>%
  st_drop_geometry() %>%
  select(NAME, DIVISION) %>%
  mutate(ID = tolower(NAME))

# get state data, convert to sf, join with division data
states <- maps::map("state", plot = FALSE, fill = TRUE) %>%
  st_as_sf() %>%
  left_join(div_dat)
#> Joining with `by = join_by(ID)`

# option 1change crs, make valid, change back
orig_crs <- st_crs(states)
states_change_crs <- states %>%
  st_transform(3857) %>%
  st_make_valid() %>%
  st_transform(crs = orig_crs)

# option 2 sf_use_s2(FALSE)
sf_use_s2(FALSE)
#> Spherical geometry (s2) switched off
states_s2false <- states


# create division polygons
div_1 <- states_change_crs %>%
  group_by(DIVISION) %>% 
  summarize()

div_2 <- states_s2false %>%
  group_by(DIVISION) %>%
  summarize()

# plot it #1
p1 <- ggplot() + 
  theme_void() +
  geom_sf(data = states_change_crs, 
          aes(fill = as.numeric(DIVISION)), 
          color = 'white') +
  geom_sf(data = div_1, 
          color = 'black', 
          fill = NA,
          size = 1) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c() +
  coord_sf(crs = 5070) +
  labs(fill = NULL)          

# plot #2
p2 <- ggplot() +
  theme_void() + 
  geom_sf(data = states_s2false,
          aes(fill = as.numeric(DIVISION)),
          color = 'white') +
  geom_sf(data = div_2,
          color = 'black',
          fill = NA,
          size = 1) + 
  scale_fill_viridis_c() + 
  coord_sf(crs = 5070) +
  labs(fill = NULL)

p1 + p2
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using `{tigris}` for getting the census divisions you can consider it also as the source for the state polygons; the package was *made* for that.

By doing that you would sidestep the by now superseded `{maps}` package. It has had a long and fruitful life - did you know it comes from S days, and is a few months older than R itself? But it does belong to a certain (less demanding) age and we really should thank it for its service, and move on.

So consider a small update of your code; what it does is:

- keeps the geometry of `tigris::states()` present / ie. removes the `sf::st_drop_geometry()` call
- filters the states by abbreviation to get rid of far flung territories such as the Virgin Islands, Guam & Alaska and Hawaii, leaving the lower 48
- the rest of your code - creating division polygons and plotting them - is left basically unchanged, only replacing the states object by the div_dat from tigris

I believe the map serves the intended purpose, and in addition the code is somewhat more concise.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tigris)
library(sf)

div_dat <- states(cb = FALSE, resolution = '20m') %>%
  filter(!STUSPS %in% c('HI', 'AK', 'PR', 'GU', 'VI', 'AS', 'MP')) %>% 
  select(NAME, DIVISION) 

# create division polygons
div <- div_dat %>%
  group_by(DIVISION) %>% 
  summarize()

# plot it
ggplot() + 
  theme_void() +
  geom_sf(data = div_dat, 
          aes(fill = as.numeric(DIVISION)), 
          color = 'white') +
  geom_sf(data = div, 
          color = 'black', 
          fill = NA,
          size = 1) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c() +
  coord_sf(crs = 5070) +
  labs(fill = NULL)
```

[image: map of lower 48 with census divisions]